# Detecting duplicate jquery elements in a javascript array

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, object-literal

So I have a form that displays a table with 2 checkboxes per row. When the form is submitted, I am trying to ajax the rows which had at least one checkbox selected to the backend.

Markup:

```
<form id="my_form">
   <table>
     <tr data-id="1">
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="js-option-1"></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" class="js-option-2"></td>
     </tr> 
     <!-- etc -->
   </table>
</form>
```

So I have an event handler that attempts to build an array of objects to send to the backend:

```
$("#my_form").live 'submit', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  rows = []
  $("input:checked").each () ->
    rows.push row
  objects = []
  $.each objects, (index, value) ->
    object = {
      id: $(@).attr("data-id")
      option_1: $(@).find("js-option-1").val()
      option_2: $(@).find("js-option-2").val()
    }
    objects.push object
  # ajax code
```

The problem, of course, is that if both options are checked, I end up with two objects in the array and thus reduntant data being sent.

I tried to get around this on both arrays by trying to detect duplicates and ignore pushing in that case:

```
$("input:checked").each () ->
  row = $(@).closest("tr")
  if $.inArray(row, rows) == -1 #if no duplicate
    rows.push row

# or 

if $.inArray(object, objects) == -1
  objects.push object
```

Both of these approaches failed, however, since I assume the mechanism for comparing object literals and jquery objects results in them being considered not equal even though they are identical in all usual respects. Any other ideas?

Comment: You understand `live` has been deprecated for years, and was *removed* in v1.9...

Comment: compare the native DOM nodes

Comment: If both checkboxes are checked you're sending redundant data...why not just use radio buttons, then you won't need to check at all?

Comment: Why are parentheses missing? What is `->` meaning? Is this some alternative form of javascript syntax?

Comment: @crush - coffeeScript

Comment: Oh, ok. Been seeing this more and more, and was losing my mind. Is this question tagged wrong then?

Comment: @crush: I've added the `coffeescript` tag. I was 49%/51% on removing the `javascript` tag.

Comment: Seems like it'd be a lot easier to wire up the checkboxes such that when you've got none checked on a row, all the other related inputs are disabled. Then you can just serialize the whole form and not have to worry about it at that point.

Comment: FWIW, your first code block uses `row` without defining it. (The second code block does define it).

Comment: @crush: I've removed the `javascript` tag now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161517/should-pure-coffeescript-questions-tag-javascript Although in the end, this is much more about logic and jQuery than it is about either language.

Comment: Older app, still using older jquery, which is why live is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use selector

```
$(':checked').closest('tr')
```

So that your selection logic doesn't include duplicates in the first place.
Or if you prefer the logic the other way around, this is more obvious:

```
$('tr').has(':checked')
```

Comment: This probably is the answer. Could use a **lot** better explanation. Or indeed any.

Comment: Added some, but can't come up with better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't iterate over collection of `input:checked`, but on `tr:has(:checked)`, that way you'll only process each row that has at least one option checked once.

try: http://jsfiddle.net/NrHQ4/ (sorry, no Coffee)

```
$('#my_form').on('submit', function(e){
    var $this = $(this), rows = $this.find('tr:has(:checked)'), objects = [];
    rows.each( function(){
        var $row = $(this);
        objects.push({
            id :  $row.data('id'),
            option_1 : $row.find('.js-option-1').is(':checked'),
            option_2 : $row.find('.js-option-2').is(':checked')
        });
    });
    console.log( objects );
    e.preventDefault();
});
```